# PHP ocultar botón con display:none

Tags: php

por favor su ayuda: 
Estoy tratando de que un botón al momento de usar un ciclo while aparezca oculto, pero se sigue mostrando, alguna solución ? :

```
  while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
     {      
            $table .= '<tr>';
            $table .= '<td>'. $fila['id_cie10'].'</td>';
            $table .= '<td>'. $fila['ccie10'].'</td>';
            $table .= '<td>'. $fila['diagnostico'].'</td>';
            $table .= '<td> <input type = "button" value="Editar" class="btn btn-default"></td>';
            $table .= '<td> <input type = "button" value="Borrar" class="btn btn-danger"></td>';
            $table .= '<td> <input type = "button" value="Actualizar" **class="btn btn-primary style="display: none;"/></td>';
            $table .= '</tr>'**;
     }
```

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste los asteriscos?, ya que veo que usas bootstrap, puedes agregar una clase llamada `hidden`

Comment: Los asteriscos y las comillas estan mal cerradas

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo con `bootstrap`. Como puedes observar, en la segunda fila utilizo el atributo `hidden` para ocultar el botón. Este atributo es el que debes usar en la ultima línea de tu ciclo.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td>id_cie10</td>
    <td>ccie10</td>
    <td>diagnostico</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-info">Editar</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-warning">Borrar</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id_cie10</td>
    <td>ccie10</td>
    <td>diagnostico</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-info">Editar</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-warning">Borrar</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" hidden>Actualizar</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Reemplaza las filas del ejemplo con tu ciclo y en vez de `input type="button"` usa `button`

```
 while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
     {      
            $table .= '<tr>';
            $table .= '<td>'. $fila['id_cie10'].'</td>';
            $table .= '<td>'. $fila['ccie10'].'</td>';
            $table .= '<td>'. $fila['diagnostico'].'</td>';
            $table .= '<td> <button value="Editar" class="btn btn-default"></button></td>';
            $table .= '<td> <button value="Borrar" class="btn btn-danger"></button></td>';
            $table .= '<td> <button value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-primary" hidden></button></td>';
            $table .= '</tr>';
     }
```